# What is using powers of two for bitwise OR and AND like this called?

Tags: terminology, bit-manipulation

I have a set of variables and I'm doing this:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 8 /* etc. */;
int result = a | c | d;
```

The point is so I can do something like:

```
if(result & a) {
    // stuff
}
```

I know this is common, I just don't know the word for it. Is there a word for this? Is there a word for the result variable?

Comment: *Masks* would be one common term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **bit field**  would describe what you are creating.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Answer (score 0):

Bit flags, or flags for short. They are also *technically* bit fields, but a very special case, where each field is just one bit wide.